# express js orm2 mysql returns Object

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, express

I use express for nodejs

```
var orm = require('orm');    
app.use(orm.express("mysql://root@127.0.0.1/daat", {
        define: function (db, models, next) {
            var question_model =  db.define('question', {

                title    : { type: "text" }
            }, {
                methods : {
                    fullName: function () {
                        return this.title;
                    }
                }
            });
            models.question = question_model;
            next();
        }
    }));
```

and the route is plain

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    req.models.question.find({id: 4}, function(err, question) {
        console.log( question );
    });
});
```

and I get undefined as the output.

Comment: Is there an error? `console.log(err);`

Comment: damn :-) that was it, wrong table name - forgot the 's'. thanks @loganfsmyth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is coming back empty then it is very likely that there is an error. You should always check for the presence of an `Error` object in `err` before processing the results of a callback.